# Does Ubuntu store passwords from failed login attempts?

Tags: login, password, security

This is probably a stupid question, but if I type in an incorrect password while attempting to log into my account, does that password get stored anywhere? Assuming that I don't have any third-party key loggers on my computer, is there any way to access those incorrectly typed passwords?

I'm asking about this because sometimes I type a correct password for something else as my Ubuntu account password by mistake, and I'd hate for that password to be compromised. I wasn't able to find an answer to this question online, but of course there might be one out there somewhere.

I know that I could scour the Ubuntu source code to find my answer, but if anyone knows the answer already, that would be preferable.

Comment: Not by default, but I believe it can be configured to do so. All that happens is an entry in `/var/log/auth.log` about a failed authentication.